# Finding elements from multiple columns of one dataframe that are not in multiple columns of another

Tags: r, tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)
```

I have two dataframes (see sample code at bottom) called Df1 and Df2. I want to find phone numbers in Df1 (from all the columns) that are not in any of the phone number columns in Df2.

First, I restructure Df1 so that there is only one Id per row.

```
Df1<-Df1 %>% 
gather(key, value, -Id) %>%
filter(!is.na(value)) %>% 
select(-key) %>% 
group_by(Id) %>% 
filter(!duplicated(value)) %>% 
mutate(Phone=paste0("Phone_",1:n())) %>% 
spread(Phone, value)
```

Next, I rename Df2 and then use a join to find only Ids in Df1 that are in Df2.

```
Df2<-Df2%>%set_names(c("Id","Ph1","Ph2"))
DfJoin<-left_join(Df2,Df1,by="Id")
```

This is where I'm stuck. I want to find all the numbers in Df1 (Phone1 Phone2, and Phone 3) that are not in Df2 (Ph1 and Ph2). Below are some ideas for code. I tried many variations of this idea but could not find a way to achieve what I want. The final product should just be a table with the phone numbers(s) in any Df1 column that are not in any Df2 column together with the associated Id. I'm also wondering if there is another join or set operation that would achieve this in a more efficient way?

```
 DfJoin<-DfJoin%>%mutate(New=if_else(! DfJoin[2:3] %in% DfJoin[4:6]),1,0)

 DfJoin<-DfJoin%>%filter(! DfJoin[2:3] %in% DfJoin[2:4])
```

*Sample Data:*

*Dataframe 1:*

```
Id<-c(199,148,148,145,177,165,144,121,188,188,188,111)
Ph1<-c(6532881717,6572231223,6541132112,6457886543,6548887777,7372222222,6451123425,6783450101,7890986543,6785554444,8764443344,6453348736)
Ph2<-c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,7372222222,NA,NA,NA,6785554444,NA,NA)

Df1<-data.frame(Id,Ph1,Ph2)
```

*Dataframe 2:*

```
Id2<-c(199,148,142,145,177,165,144,121,182,109,188,111)
Phone1<-c(6532881717,6572231223,6541132112,6457886543,6548887777,7372222222,6451123425,6783450101,7890986543,6785554400,8764443344,6453348736)
 Phone2<-c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,7372222222,NA,NA,NA,6785554444,NA,NA)

 Df2<-data.frame(Id2,Phone1,Phone2)
```

Comment: In base R, you could use something like `setdiff(unlist(Df1[("Ph1", "Ph2")]), unlist(Df2[c("Phone1", "Phone2")]))` to get all phone numbers in Df1 that are not in Df1. `setdiff` removes NAs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to think about this problem:

1. You have a set of phone numbers in `df1` for each ID number.
2. You have a set of phone numbers in `df2` for each ID number.
3. You want to find, within each ID, the [set difference](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SetDifference.html) between `df1` and `df2`.

You can do this by mapping the base R function `setdiff()` onto your joined dataframe.  To do this, you need to convert your data frames into list-column format, where all the phone numbers for each ID are present as a list in a "cell"  of the dataframe.  This is easily done by combining `group_by()`, `summarize()` and `list()`.

```
# create example data
Id <- c(199,148,148,145,177,165,144,121,188,188,188,111)
ph1 <- c(6532881717,6572231223,6541132112,6457886543,6548887777,7372222222,6451123425,6783450101,7890986543,6785554444,8764443344,6453348736)
ph2 <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,7372222222,NA,NA,NA,6785554444,NA,NA)

df1 <- data.frame(Id, ph1, ph2)

Id2 <- c(199,148,142,145,177,165,144,121,182,109,188,111)
phone1 <- c(6532881717,6572231223,6541132112,6457886543,6548887777,7372222222,6451123425,6783450101,7890986543,6785554400,8764443344,6453348736)
phone2 <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,7372222222,NA,NA,NA,6785554444,NA,NA)

df2 <- data.frame(Id=Id2, phone1, phone2)


# convert the data to list-column format
df1.listcol <- df1 %>%
    gather(col, phone, -Id) %>%
    na.omit() %>%
    group_by(Id) %>%
    summarize(phone_list1 = list(phone)) 

df2.listcol <- df2 %>%
    gather(col, phone, -Id) %>%
    na.omit() %>%
    group_by(Id) %>%
    summarize(phone_list2 = list(phone))
```

Take a look at these dataframes to make sure you understand how we've reformatted them.  Obviously, we could save a few lines of code by making this conversion process into a function, and then calling the function on each of `df1` and `df2`, but I didn't do that here.

```
# join the two listcol dfs by Id, then map setdiff on the two columns
result <- 
    df1.listcol %>%
    left_join(df2.listcol, by='Id') %>%
    mutate(only_list_1 = map2(phone_list1, phone_list2, ~setdiff(.x, .y))) %>%
    select(Id, only_list_1) %>%
    unnest()

result
```

The `result` is

```
Id  only_list_1
148 6541132112
188 7890986543
188 6785554444
```

Comment: This is a great solution. Tested it out on my real data and it worked. It's great that this allows any number of phone number columns.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `anti_join(a, b, by = "x1")`

This basically gives you all rows in a which are not in b

```
DfJoin <- anti_join(Df1, Df2, by = "Id")
```

[tidyr_dplyr cheatsheet](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf)

Use the above cheatsheet for data manipulation in tidyverse

Comment: This will find all the `Id`s in `Df1` that are not in `Df2`.  I think the OP wanted to compare phone numbers, not just `Id`s.